# JS Prevent unsecured code from accessing the window object

Tags: javascript, security, browser, sandbox

my latest app features - and depends on - the ability to create plugins for the app.

Many of the default plugins' script files are stored on the app's server, however I'd like to expand out soon and allow users to import and write their own plugins, which means the app is running untrusted, unverified code. Now, I'm aware that there is more than enough evidence across the internet explaining why running untrusted code is a bad idea, but as my app requires this functionality, I'm not left with much choice.

So the solution I've come up with is the following:

```
export default function sandbox(script: string, API: {[key: string]: any}): Partial<Plugin> {
    // language=JavaScript
    const keys: (keyof API)[] = Object.keys(API) as (keyof API)[];
    const fn = new Function(...keys, `const window=void 0,document=void 0,Function=void 0,eval=void 0;${script}`);
    return fn.apply({}, keys.map(i => API[i]))
}
```

After a quick test in the browser, this code works, however, I added the `Function = void 0, eval = void 0` bit, after I discovered that running the following code within the script reveals the `window` object:

```
const win = new Function (`return window`)();
```

I'm wondering whether there are any other dangerous (or potentially dangerous) security holes in this system that I may have missed, and how I would patch them, without limiting the functionality of the plugins too much.

PS. Several of the default plugins rely on browser APIs for UI/Networking functionality, thus overwriting the `Function` and `eval` values is a sub-optimal *fix*.

Comment: Depending on how your app is used, you may not need to worry about this too much. If a user has to go out of their way to import their own custom plugin, then any malicious code is... well, written by them. If, however, you allow people to *publish* plugins, you'll definitely want some kind of verification process where you manually check the code before allowing common users to download it.

Comment: Does this code execute at all? Because `script: string` is invalid Javascript. JS doesn't have type checking (Typescript does)

Comment: @JeremyThille Yes, this is TypeScript. The first code box is typescript, the second is plain JavaScript.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Publishing plugins is going to be a large part of the app, but manual checking is a viable option, until you see published content outside of the plugin repository, where it can't be verified

Comment: If you really want to do this, search, whether there is a battle-tested, and long standing solution, and read about that very carefully. There might not be at all. Towards your immediate question: `(function(){}).constructor('alert("rip")')()`